# d3 default conditional percentage statement for bar height

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want the values to be compared to the highest value if the value is less than or equal to a percentage it should only show that percentage and nothing less as far as the height of the bar goes.

Here's what I have

`var maxValue = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.yColumn; });
     var data [20, 1000, 3000, 400]`

```
var bars = g.selectAll("rect").data(data);
bars.attr("height", function(d){if (d.amount/d.maxvalue <= "12%") { return "12%" };});
```

I know this is incorrect syntax, but I think I have the right idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*(before anything: don't do that. For whatever design reasons you have, don't change the size - width or height - of the bars in a bar chart like this. This is lying with data. If you have to do this for showing small values, make that change clear to the readers)*

This is the role that you want:

```
.attr("height", function(d){
    if (d.amount/d.maxvalue <= 0.12) { 
        return d.maxvalue*0.12;
    } else {
        return d.amount;
    }
});
```

Here is a demo snippet. In this snippet, the bars' width are set by the data, but if a bar is less than 12% of the maximum value (in this case, the bar corresponding to the datapoint `2`) its width is converted to 12% of the maximum value:

```js
var data = [60, 80, 150, 310, 2, 230, 260, 320];
  
var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
  .data(data).enter().append("div");
 
divs.style("width", function(d) { 
  if(d/(d3.max(data)) <= .12){return (d3.max(data))*.12 + "px";
  }else{return d + "px";}})
.attr("class", "divchart")
.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```css
.divchart {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You can easily see that `2` is way bigger than it should be.

Comment: Not sure how your's differs from mine. I placed your height code in mine and nothing appears to be changed. Here's my maxValue var --  'var maxValue = d3.max(data, function (d){ return d[yColumn]; });'

Comment: Examine your code: it uses strings, not numbers. Also, it returns "12%", but 12% of what? Besides that, `maxValue` is different from `maxvalue`, and neither can be used with that `data` array. To finish, there is no `else` to the `if` condition.

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive but I mean the end result is the same. Nothing changes and no errors occur in the console. If my data values  var data = [
        {
         
          "amount": 20,
          
        },
        {
        
          "amount": 8,
         
        },
        {
          
          "amount": 100,
          
        },
        {
         
          "amount": 40,
          
        }
      ]; The "8" amount should display as 12 percent of the largest number and it still doesn't not show

Comment: Well, if nothing changes you probably have *another* problem somewhere in your code, because you can easily see that the math is correct, the demo snippet is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

```
var bars = g.selectAll("rect").data(data);
bars.attr("height", function(d){if (d.amount/d.maxvalue <= "12%") { return "12%" };});
```

Could you post also the data associated to each bar? What is *d.maxvalue*. Looking at your code it seems that each bar has in its data an attribute called *maxvalue*, how do you calculate *maxvalue*?

In the following snippet I'm using a data array in the same way you do. Then, I compare the single heights with the max heigh in the array and if it is 12% of the max I set the height of that bar as the 12% of the max, otherwise the bar will have the related height contained in the array.

```js
var data = [20, 50, 400, 100]

var maxValue = d3.max(data, function(d) { 

return d; 
});

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var g = svg.append("g")

var bars = g.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect");

bars.attr("height", function(d){
 if (d/maxValue <= 0.12) 
    return d*0.12 ;
  else
    return d
    }
)
.attr("x",function(d, i){return i*(10 + 10)})
.attr("width",10)
.attr("class","bar")
```

```css
svg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px
}

rect{
  fill: #27ae60
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Just added that info

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13881601)

Comment: thank you userlkjsflkdsvm, I edited my answer with a possible solution using your data. 
@Julian, sorry about that